# Image won't display with Seadragon Ajax Controol Toolkit

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, deepzoom, seadragon

I've followed all the steps outlined in http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/jsenior/Seadragon-Ajax-Control-Quick-Start-Guide?format=progressive, as well as, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/gg413362.aspx.

The error " JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getError'" pops up, and then a broswer with just the zoom in/out, etc controls, without any image.

Is there something wrong with my sourceURL? It's the only thing I can think of that would do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please include your code

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to look at your code to see what the problem is. Do you have it posted somewhere?

That version of Seadragon Ajax is very old now. The latest is called OpenSeadragon:

http://openseadragon.github.io/

You might give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

source URL must be inside of "working data" of your xmlproject.
ex: ~/xmlproject/Working Data/image.xml